# Cannot Write to Secondary Hard Drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I have a secondary storage drive on my computer mounted at `/media/user_name/Data`.
I get this error when trying to create a new directory:

`user_name@cpu:/media/user_name/Data mkdir test`

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system

`df -h` shows it mount at:

```
...
/dev/sdc2       466G   77G  390G  17% /media/user_name/Data
```

I follow instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/how-to-fix-external-hard-disk-read-only) to remount it as read/write

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdc2
```

I try to make a directory again:

```
cd /media/user_name/Data/
mkdir test
```

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No such file or directory

I tried solving it with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096849/cant-make-new-dir-with-mkdir) solution but the same error exists.

The weird thing is I was able to write to this drive last week. I haven't done anything except boot into windows (on a third drive) and access and write data to the Data drive. I primarily use this drive for storage and to pass files between Windows and Ubuntu.

Checking disks, this is the info for it

```
Size 500 GB — 418 GB free (16.3% full)
Device /dev/sdc2
UUID 20B666B0B66685DE
Partition Type 
Contents NTFS — Mounted at /media/user_name/Data
```

Comment: *I haven't done anything except boot into windows* Well, that would do it if it has the default setting of Fast Startup. Boot again Windows, disable Fast Startup and shutdown.

Comment: I'm a derp. Thank you for the reply. That fixed it

Comment: We all had to learn about that new feature at some point. It isn't something easily deduced even for experienced users, if you don't know it, you won't guess.

Answer (score 0):

yes i know the answer the reason behind this is that your PC is not completely shut down you have to off the fast shut down options

step 1 Go to power setting

step 2 Go to additional power settings

step 3 uncheck the fast shut down option

for the further details see this video

[can not write on secondary disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KdtMQjbWzk)